# JavaScript Primitives and Stack

Tags: javascript, stack, callstack, primitive

I'm trying to understand how primitive's value is changed in the Stack.
Let's say i declare and initialize four primitives:

```
let myNumber = 12;
let myBool = true;
let myString = "hello";
let myNull = null;
```

As i know, they will be stored in the stack like this:
[stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT3Ca.jpg)

Then, if i do:

```
myNumber = 30;
```

Question: 
Will the javascript engine pop myNull, myString, myBool from the stack (and store them somewhere else in the memory), then change the value of myNumber to 30 and then push back myBool, myString, and myNull into the stack?

Comment: iirc the call stack is used for the js interpreter to help maintain its position in the script when subroutines are called. a variable declaration is not a subroutine so I don't see the call stack being involved at all in your example.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack

Comment: "Call stack" usually refers to function calls. See: [Understanding the JavaScript call stack](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-the-javascript-call-stack-861e41ae61d4/). What are you referring to here?

Comment: https://youtu.be/9ooYYRLdg_g?t=504 This is what i'm referring to. The video explains how primitives get 'pushed' into a part of memory called "stack". However, it does not explain what happens when we change the value of a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of values to the primitive variables are the daily basis task. The key point to understand here is that when we are assigning a value to a variable actually we are assigning the address to the variable from the heap as we know the primitive variables are immutable in js, hence if there is a change in the value then there is the change in the address there are referring to.
If we go by this concept than in our call stack we are actually storing the address of the heap memory location rather than the actual value. 
You could refer to the below medium link to have a better understanding of the same.
I hope it helps. :)

https://medium.com/@ethannam/javascripts-memory-model-7c972cd2c239

(Note: Also please go through the garbage collector concept from the official js docs to have a further deep understanding of the primitive variables assignment and garbage collection. :) )